# Arraylist synchronization for add only call

Tags: multithreading, arraylist, synchronization

I have a question regarding synchronizing Array List. I am using an ArayList in a multi threaded environment with Callable interface. I pass an Arraylist object to the Callable method where all the child threads add an entry into the arraylist.
I don't use the arraylist to Iterate anywhere in the Child thread classes. Should I need to synchronize the Arraylist still even if I do only add into that?

Snippet below, please help

```
main Class        
.     
.   
.    
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();             
ImplCallable implCallable = new ImplCallable (arrList);              
.        
.       
.         
ImplCallable Class        

ImplCallable (ArrayList<String> arrList)          
{      
   this.arrList = arrList;          
}       
call()        
{         
.            
.       
.     
.        
synchronized(arrList)    
{             
    arrList.add(addString);           
}     

}
```

Regards
Subash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to synchronize the inserts.

ArrayList is not synchronized, see

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

So if you are adding elements to it concurrently from several threads you must synchronize it, because you are modifying concurrently its inner structure.

From javadoc:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
> ```